# SQLite Database not found when deploying a QML app

Tags: javascript, sqlite, qml

I've been working on an application with Qt Quick 2 entirely realized with QML and Javascript functions. (Except from the main.cpp which is detailed below)

For the model, I've been using the LocalStorage functionality. My app is working fine on my computer and I exported it to other computers. On the other computers, the app launches, but none of the dataBase functions are working.

I then discovered that the default path for the localStorage was `User\AppData\Local\MyAppName\QML\OfflineStorage\Databases`

And that it could be changed using `setOfflineStoragePath();`

Main.cpp:

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
  QGuiApplication app(argc, argv);

  QQmlApplicationEngine engine;
  engine.load(QUrl(QStringLiteral("qrc:///main.qml")));
  engine.setOfflineStoragePath(QString("./"));  

  return app.exec();
}
```

Again this is working fine on my computer but doesn't produce any result on other computers. (The database folder is created at the specified path, with the .sqlite and .ini file in it)

What I've seen is that on other computers, only the .ini seems to be created and never the .sqlite

I would have think of an error in my code, but it really runs fine every time I compile my project (no matter the computer) directly from Qt creator.

Thank you

PS: I'm using the debug conf (instead of the release) in the compiler menu (down left)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While deploying qt applications using sqlite, you must deploy `Qt5Sql.dll` in the app directory and `qsqlite.dll`(this is found in plugin directory. Ex: Qt5.3.1\5.3\mingw482_32\plugins\sqldrivers ) in `<app directory>/sqldrivers`. This might be the solution for you problem. From the question I am not sure whether you have done so.

Comment: That was something like that, I had some of those lib that you describe, but I just paste copy a bunch of them. Really deploying QML apps is a mess...